# Making a change password and change email address in one form

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently programming php, and enjoying it.
I know how to code a script that will update a user's email address or password in different processes.  I need to update them in one form.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I need to update one of them, if he didn't enter a password then update the email, if he didn't enter the email update the password, if he entered both update both..
the script I am currently coding has been twirling around my mind and I have lost myself over and over and over...

update_settings_process.php: (I have Updated the script!!)

```
   <?php
   error_reporting(1);
   session_start();
   include("../common/config.php");
   include("../common/conn.php");

   $case = '';
    $error_str = '';
   //email:
    $email  =   stripslashes($_REQUEST['email_address']);

    //password:
   $old_password                =   trim($_REQUEST['old_password']);
   $password                        =   trim($_REQUEST['password']);
   $conf_password               =   trim($_REQUEST['conf_password']);
   $get_users_qry   =   "Select password From users where username = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."' AND password = '".md5($old_password)."' AND status = 1";
   $get_users       =   $db->get_row($get_users_qry,ARRAY_A);
$qry     = "Select email   from  users where email  = '$email' and username != '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'";
$res     = mysql_query($qry);
   echo 'Email:' . $email;
   echo '<p>';
   echo 'Old Password: '. $old_password;
   echo '<p>';
   echo 'Password:' . $password;
   echo '<p>';
   echo 'Confrim Password:' . $conf_password;
   echo '<p>';

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && (strlen($password) > 5) && $get_users && !mysql_num_rows($res))
{
        //update email and password
    $update_password     =  mysql_query("UPDATE users
                            SET
                            password='".md5($password)."' where username = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'");
    $update_email  =  mysql_query("UPDATE users
                            SET
                            email='".$email."' where username = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'");
       echo 'Email and Password Has been Updated!';
       die();
}

if ($email == '' && (strlen($password) == 0))
{

    $error_str .= "There is nothing to update";
    echo $error_str;
    die();
}

if ($email == '' && (strlen($password) == 0))
{
    $error_str .= "Use a secure Password";
    echo $error_str;
    $case = 0;
    die();
}
else
{
    if($email == '' && (strlen($password) < 5))
    {
        $error_str .= "Password must be atleast 5 characters";
        echo $error_str;
        $case = 0;
        die();
    }
    else
    {
    if ($email == ''  &&  $password != $conf_password)
    {
        $error_str .= "Passwords Do not Match";
        echo $error_str;
        $case = 0;
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        if($email == '' && !$get_users)
        {
            $error_str .= "Please enter correct old password <br>";
            echo $error_str;
            $case = 0;
            die();
        }

    else
    {
          //update password only!
        if(strlen($password) == 0)
        {
            die();
        }
        else
        {
        $update_password     =  mysql_query("UPDATE users
                            SET
                            password='".md5($password)."' where username = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'");

        echo "done-SEPARATOR-Password changed successfully";
        exit();
        }
    }
            }
}
}

if(strlen($password) == 0)
        {
    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        $error_str .="Invalid Email <br>";
        echo $error_str;
        $case = 0;
        die();

    }
    else
    {
        $qry     = "Select email   from  tbl_admin where email  = '$email' and username != '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'";
        $res     = mysql_query($qry);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res))
        {
            $error_str = "$email already exist<br>";
            $case = 0;


        }
    else
    {
            //update email only!
            $update_email  =  mysql_query("UPDATE users
                            SET
                            email='".$email."' where username = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'");

            echo "done-SEPARATOR-Email address changed successfully";
            die();
        }
    }
}


    if($case = 0)
{
    echo $error_str;
    die();
}
?>
```

I have really lost myself in there, and I couldn't figure out why because of that..
I have updated the script:
it can update password and email at the same time
it can update password only
it can not update email only.. <-- im stuck here
here's the update email only part:

```
if(strlen($password) == 0)
        {
    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        $error_str .="Invalid Email <br>";
        echo $error_str;
        $case = 0;
        die();

    }
    else
    {
        $qry     = "Select email   from  tbl_admin where email  = '$email' and username != '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'";
        $res     = mysql_query($qry);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res))
        {
            $error_str = "$email already exist<br>";
            $case = 0;


        }
    else
    {
            //update email only!
            $update_email  =  mysql_query("UPDATE users
                            SET
                            email='".$email."' where username = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_BALANCE_FRONT']['name']."'");

            echo "done-SEPARATOR-Email address changed successfully";
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are updating a persons identity in one go?! Very silly

Comment: do you think should I add tabs? so each tab has 3 columns? that's the silly part, i need to make the widget look quite big!

Comment: probably not a good idea to call your users retards...

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your `if-clauses`. Try changing them to something like this:

`$email == ''`

Answer (score 0):

1) = is the assignment operator, == is the comparison operator, which you weirdly used correctly with the strlen($password) comparison. The mnemonic is "Twice is for T(w)sets, Once is for Owssignment" (works best in a North English accent).

2) You're doing something rather odd with the strlen() function. strlen() *always* returns an integer (until someone invents half-letters). Consequently, strlen == '' is a bad, bad test. What you would want that line to look like is this:

```
   if ($email = '' && (strlen($password) == 0))
```

(though why you didn't use strlen() both times puzzles me!)

3) Do not, not even jokingly, use the word 'retard' in code, or at least be bright enough not to post it publicly. It's ableist and, frankly, stupid. There are loads of people on this board who are extremely experienced and would, were they not better (wo)men, think you to be one for using a single = to test. Never call your users, or indeed anyone, a 'retard'. It's not funny.

Comment: I have made another script, i can see that most of it is working thanks to you, im only stuck at this part and if it's fixed everything is fixed:
`  if(mysql_num_rows($res))
  {
   $error_str = "$email already exist<br>";
   echo $error_str;
   $case = 0;
   die();
  }`

Comment: If I see it properly, you have a conditional here that lacks an assertion.
You say:

`if(mysql_num_rows($res)){ ... some function ... }`

There is, basically, nothing to evaluate in the code. mysql_num_rows() returns an integer, so you should test it being equal to something.
Also note that mysql_num_rows() is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. The PHP reference has more details on it - do you know how to use it?